# iOS receipt Blob or File

Tags: php, ios, mysql, database

I am dealing with server side validation of iOS subscription receipts. The receipt comes in as a large Base64 which gets validated.

My question is, I thought about storing the receipt as either a MediumBlob or a Long Text but I was wondering if it would be more efficient for the db if I would just save the large Base64 string to a text file and then store the path to the file instead of putting the whole receipt in the db.

Thanks!

Comment: base64 has a ~33% space overhead. you could decode it back to original if you're worried about disk space. but otherwise, we can't answer for you. it depends ENTIRELY on how you're going to use this blob.

Comment: We would essentially be reading it out of the db into a variable and then sending it off for validation.